# Keep UITableView padding on header but no in separator on IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, separator

with the transition on iOS7 the separator has 15px padding on left. I know that i can remove this padding with separator inset feature on the UITableView setting in the xib file, but i need to keep heading text with padding. How to do it?

default:

[image]

with custom on separator inset to 0:

[image]

i need to keep separators like figure 2, but the header with "2013" like picture 1.

Comment: Do you have only one section in tableview or you have more?

Comment: Nope, one for all the days where i have notification.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

for Seperator you can set it via Storyboard

and for header make a custom header like this

```c
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
  UIView *viewHeader = [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 28)];
  UILabel *lblTitle = [UILabel.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 3, 136, 21)];

  [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
  [lblTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [lblTitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
  [lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [viewHeader addSubview:lblTitle];

  return viewHeader;
}
```

give it any particular height. and give it any text.
make an Array for section Headers which will contain your years.

Comment: where viewHeader stand for? it's not initialized

Comment: yeah, i know but i don't understand what i have to put instead of viewHeader, that's a delegate function and i don't see any viewHeader init inside :P

Comment: viewHeader is basically a UIView that we will return for use as a Header Section.
`-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` is a delegate function. place it in your UITableView View Controller .

Comment: i don't see anything instead of 2013 now O_O

Comment: did you make an NSMutableArray and seperately add yours years in it ? 

if not do it. and in you `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:` give `[lblTitle setText:[array objectAtIndex:section]`

Answer (score 51):

**USING SWIFT AND STORYBOARD**

In storyboard you can set different separator insets for the TableView (header) and for Cells (separators).

Set the separator inset for cell to 0, by selecting the cell in Storyboard and setting the following:

[image]

Then set the separator inset for the TableView (for the header) to 15, by selecting the TableView in Storyboard and setting the following:

[image]

**OPTIONAL:**

You may also need to set the margins on the cells to be zero programmatically to ensure that the separator goes all the way from left to right. Use this code if needed in your table view controller's swift file:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YOURCELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART...
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Works also if the table view and cells are in separate **xibs** (no storyboard).

Comment: This also works without storyboard or xibs. If you are creating your table programatically, both UITableView and UITableViewCell expose the `.separatorInset` property. Set the cell's one to `.zero` and let the table's one be the value that you want.

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` has a delegate method named `viewForHeaderInSection`. If you remove the padding an then in the delegate method add a padding and return the section header view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame), 30)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 200, 25)];

    // 15 pixel padding will come from CGRectMake(15, 5, 200, 25).
    label.text = @"2013";
    [view addSubview: label];
    return view;
}
```

You can design you header view how ever you like. For setting the height of the tableView header use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Hope it helps you... )

Comment: i think that's the solutin but it's not clear to me. i've to reimplement - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; and how to move 15px right padding inside this delegate? can you give me the example?

Comment: @AlessioCrestani>> Weekend. Sorry for being late. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set insets on table (and header/footer) and on the cell itself:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
    }    
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to create a custom header view always because sometimes its a overkill or it'll need some trial and error to make it exactly like the default section title. Instead there is a simple hack which won't need to return a custom header view. Just set your separator indent to 0 and put some leading space in the title string.

[image]

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"    Your Title";
}
```

Comment: Adding space to a string is never a valid option.

Comment: in IOS 9, at list in my case, there was no need to any spaces, just changing the separator insets moved the header text to the right place.... that was great

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indent the Section text from the left margin, here is a simple way I did it.  In the function, see the space after the first quote mark?  Just put as many spaces as you need before the start of the text.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let title: UILabel = UILabel()

        title.text = " \(sortedSections[section])"
        title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

        return title
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

in you cellForRowAtIndeaPath method add a view into cell like

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectmake(cell.frame.ori.x, cell.frame.ori.y, 20.0, cell.height)];

view.backgroundColor = desired color

[cell.containView addSubView: view];
```

add this into your first cell code and you are done

Comment: it's not a fir cell, tableview has a lot of sections. Tha's only an example.

Comment: this will do for all the section and cell and you also can conditioned it with your specific cell or section