# Add padding to Section Header in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

I created this section header title and unfortunately I don't know how to add some padding on the right.

[image: screenshot]

Here's my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let title: UILabel = UILabel()
    title.text = "Days"
    title.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    return title
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017019/keep-uitableview-padding-on-header-but-no-in-separator-on-ios7.. This seems to be answering your questions. Also how about adding 2 spaces at the end of text? title.text = "Days  "

Comment: Why not try creating a `UIView` and add your `UILabel` as a subview of that view and use auto layout constraints on the label to add some space on the side of the label?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502235/how-to-add-padding-left-on-a-uilabel-created-programmatically can help

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 5, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 20))
    label.text = "Days"
    label.textAlignment = .right
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that adjusting it in the storyboard does the trick. Click on the tableView and set the Separator Inset on Left and Right edges.  Make sure to click on the tableView and not the cell.